# Resetting manually assigned IDs to auto increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I accidentally pushed code that assigns (randomly generated between 0 and 1000000) IDs for new rows instead of auto increment. So currently this is the situation:

```
ID, Name
1, foo
2, bar
79812, baz
89991, qux
```

Luckily its not been too long before I discovered the issue, and I'm just wondering if its possible at all to reset the rows to their would-be auto incremented ids, so it looks like:

```
ID, Name
1, foo
2, bar
3, baz
4, qux
```

Comment: No, in general it isn't possible to do this, not unless you have a column which was keeping track of the original order the entire time.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess its safe to assume the rows with incorrect IDs are 1) when sorting by ID asc 2) the first number thats not in sequence (2 -> 79812) 3) until the last.

Comment: If you are certain that the `ID` values were always increasing (and never backtracking to smaller values), then you could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)` to generate the sequence you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Alter table - rename ID field and remove PK
2. Alter table - add ID field, make it PK and auto increment
3. Check data, make sure new ID has values you need
4. Drop old ID field